# Passing multiple Objects between activities (using parcelable)

Tags: java, android

So what I am trying to do is pass ObjectB from the first activity to the second. ObjectB contains another object, ObjectA. I am getting really confused as to how to implement this. Also, I am using a list in ObjectA because I am going to have multiple integer values instead of just the 1 in this example. Here is the first activity:

```
private ObjectB objB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    objB = new ObjectB();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("KEY", objB);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and the second activity:

```
private ObjectB objB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    objB = new ObjectB();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    objB = b.getParcelable("KEY");

    tv.setText(objB.obj.stage1Count);
}
```

Class for ObjectB:

```
public class ObjectB implements Parcelable{
    public ObjectA obj;

    public ObjectB() { obj = new ObjectA(); }

    public ObjectA getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public ObjectB(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public void setObj(ObjectA obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(obj, flags);
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        obj = in.readParcelable(ObjectA.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public ObjectB createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new ObjectB(in);
            }

            public ObjectB[] newArray(int size) {
                return new ObjectB[size];
            }
        };
}
```

Class for ObjectA:

```
public class ObjectA implements Parcelable{
    public int stage1Count = 1;

    public ObjectA() { ; };

    public ObjectA(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        List<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        iList.add(stage1Count);
        dest.writeList(iList);
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        List<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        iList = in.readArrayList(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        stage1Count = iList.get(0);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public ObjectA createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new ObjectA(in);
            }

            public ObjectA[] newArray(int size) {
                return new ObjectA[size];
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in first activity:

```
List<ObjectB> list = new ArrayList<ObjectB>;    
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", list);
```

And in second activity

```
List<ObjectB> list = new ArrayList<ObjectB>;
list = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("key");
```

From list get your objectB

Answer (score -1):

This was a really dumb question but I figured it out after a really long time haha. The problem is `tv.setText(objB.obj.stage1Count);`because objB.obj.stage1Count is actually an integer but for some reason it does not ring any bells when you try to use it as a string, idk maybe its something with the parceing.